# Proofing code against user being too fast?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization

I'm using the MUI slider in my React application. The twist is that I'd like it to work both as the single slider and the range slider at the sime time. The behaviour should be as in this visualisation:

https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/number-with-mental-and-neurodevelopmental-disorders-by-type?time=1993..1999&facet=none

To sum up here is the behaviour description:

1. Range Mode:
   When in "range" mode and either the maximum or minimum values are adjusted, the slider updates the range accordingly.
2. Switching to Single Value Mode:
   In "range" mode, if the maximum and minimum values become equal, the slider transitions to "single value mode" but this is only triggered on the mouse-up event.
3. Single Value Mode - Dragging:
   In "single" mode, dragging the slider handle horizontally results in a normal change of the single value.
4. Switching to Range Mode - Clicking Outside:
   In "single" mode, clicking on any value outside the current value triggers a switch to "range" mode. The slider then adjusts the range based on the clicked value and the current value. If the clicked value is less than the current value, the range becomes [clicked value, current value]. If the clicked value is equal to the current value, the range is set as [current value, clicked value].

So far I've got the code that works most of the time.

```
export default function RangeSlider({data}) {
    const [rangeValue, setRangeValue] = React.useState([2009, 2019]);
    const [singleValue, setSingleValue] = React.useState(2019);
    const [isSingleMode, setIsSingleMode] = React.useState(true);

    const yearValue = d => d.year;
    const minYear = min(data, yearValue);
    const maxYear = max(data, yearValue);
    const step = 1;

    const handleChange = (e, newValue) => {
        console.log("singleValue: " + singleValue + ", newVaalue; " + newValue)
        if (isSingleMode) {
            if (Math.abs(newValue-singleValue) > 1) {
                setRangeValue([singleValue, newValue].sort());
                setIsSingleMode(false);
            }
            else {
                setSingleValue(newValue);
            }
        }
        else {
            setRangeValue(newValue);
        }
    }

    const handleMouseUp = () => {
        if (!isSingleMode) {
            if (rangeValue[0] === rangeValue[1]) {
                setSingleValue(rangeValue[0]);
                setIsSingleMode(true);
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <Box sx={{ width: 300 }}>
            <Slider
                value={isSingleMode ? singleValue : rangeValue}
                min={minYear}
                max={maxYear}
                onChange={handleChange}
                valueLabelDisplay="auto"
                marks
                step={step}
                onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
            />
        </Box>
    );
}
```

But from time to time, in a single mode, it is possible to move (slide) the slider a bit too fast and switch to range mode unexpectedly.

Here is the console output or a "slow slide":

> singleValue: 2019, newVaalue; 2018 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2018, newVaalue; 2017 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2017, newVaalue; 2016 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2016, newVaalue; 2015 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2015, newVaalue; 2014 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2014, newVaalue; 2013 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2013, newVaalue; 2012 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2012, newVaalue; 2011 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2011, newVaalue; 2010 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2010, newVaalue; 2009 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2009, newVaalue; 2008 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2008, newVaalue; 2007 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2007, newVaalue; 2006 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2006, newVaalue; 2005 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 2004 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2004, newVaalue; 2003 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2003, newVaalue; 2002 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2002, newVaalue; 2001 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2001, newVaalue; 2000 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2000, newVaalue; 1999 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 1999, newVaalue; 1998 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 1998, newVaalue; 1997 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 1997, newVaalue; 1996 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 1996, newVaalue; 1995 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 1995, newVaalue; 1994 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 1994, newVaalue; 1993 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 1993, newVaalue; 1992 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 1992, newVaalue; 1991

And here is the output or "fast slide":

> singleValue: 2019, newVaalue; 2018 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2018, newVaalue; 2017 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2017, newVaalue; 2016 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2016, newVaalue; 2015 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2015, newVaalue; 2014 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2014, newVaalue; 2013 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2013, newVaalue; 2012 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2012, newVaalue; 2011 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2011, newVaalue; 2010 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2010, newVaalue; 2009 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2009, newVaalue; 2008 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2008, newVaalue; 2007 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2007, newVaalue; 2006 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2006, newVaalue; 2005 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 2003 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 2002,2005 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 2001,2005 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 2000,2005 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 1999,2005 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 1998,2005 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 1997,2005 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 1996,2005 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 1995,2005 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 1994,2005 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 1992,2005 RangeSlider.js:17
> singleValue: 2005, newVaalue; 1991,2005

My understanding is that the newValue is not updated fast enough to catch up with the slider?

How can I fix it?